# qemu (KVM) how to set iscsi timeout on?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, iscsi, qemu

I have opensuse 15.2 Leap on all systems

qemu  4.2.1

```
# /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 4.2.1 (openSUSE Leap 15.2)
Copyright (c) 2003-2019 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

For guest system there are two disks, one image and one iscsi target

The problem is when network down or remote host, qemu doesn`t detach broken disk or generate error. It can wait dozens of time when target asnwers. Guest VM stops normaly work and wait too

This is my kvm configuration (qemu-kvm is symlink to /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 ) :

```
   qemu-kvm -name cc-2 \
-m 8192  -machine accel=kvm -smp 8 \
-kernel /vtpool/containers/lib/vmlinuz-4.12.14-lp151.28.52-default \
-append "root=/dev/md0p1 md=0,/dev/vda,/dev/vdb  splash=silent ctype=cc-2 mitigations=auto quiet emode=ok hosted=t18" \
-initrd /vtpool/containers/lib/initrd-4.12.14-lp151.28.52-default \
-drive file=/ssd/cc-clients/containers/clients-vm-02.img,if=virtio \
 \
-device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi0 \
-device scsi-hd,bus=scsi0.0,channel=0,scsi-id=0,drive=disk0 \
-drive id=disk0,file=iscsi://10.47.0.22/iqn.2021-05.t22.cc1:b1a0e42243f2f0c073ac/0,if=none,cache=none,format=raw,media=disk,discard=unmap \
 \
-boot c \
-device virtio-net-pci,mac=00:22:02:1a:10:02,netdev=cc2e.0 \
-netdev tap,ifname=cc2e.0,id=cc2e.0,script=/etc/kvm/virtual0-up,vhost=on \
-net nic,macaddr=00:22:02:1b:10:02 -net tap,ifname=cc2e.1,script=/etc/kvm/sanbr0-up \
-vnc 172.16.10.18:102 \
-pidfile /var/run/kvm/containers/cc-2.pid \
-daemonize
```

So, question is how to set some timeout for iscsi target, to generate error or detach disk on kvm side ? For example, if physical disk with image damage, KVM would catch it and guest  have an errors. How to do same with iscsi ?